# Subsetting r data.table with grep

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to subset a data.table to select columns but can't seem to figure out how to do indexing from a vector.

```
mtcars <- data.table(mtcars )


cols <- colnames(mtcars)[c(
grep( "a" , colnames( mtcars )) ,
which(  colnames( mtcars ) =="mpg"   )
)]

# this is an error
mtcars[ , cols ]

#this is a vector - not a subsetted data.table
mtcars[ , .( cols) ]

#this too
mtcars[ , eval(cols) ]
```

Comment: You need `mtcars[, ..cols]`, [see here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md#new-features-1) for an explanation

Comment: You can always do `subset(mtcars, select = cols)`

Answer (score 0):

In dplyr this would would return the desired result: 
`mtcars <- mtcars %>% dplyr:: select(contains("a"), "mpg")`